# What does Herstein mean by 'centroid of a ring'?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, rngs

I'm currently reading Herstein's *Noncommutative Rings*, and the definition of the *centroid* of a ring is on page 46 of the book.

Let $\text{End}(R)$ be the ring of endomorphisms of the additive group $R$. For each $a \in R$, define $$\begin{array}{rccc}T_a: & R & \longrightarrow & R \\ & x & \longmapsto & xa  \end{array}$$ and $$\begin{array}{rccc}L_a: & R & \longrightarrow & R \\ & x & \longmapsto & ax  \end{array}.$$

Now, let $\text{B}(R)$ be the subring of $\text{End}(R)$ generated by all elements $L_a$, and $T_a$.

**Centroid definition**

> The centroid of $R$ is the set of elements in $\text{End}(R)$ which commute element-wise with $\text{B}(R)$.

Since I'm Googling for some examples on this definition, but I found none (even wikipedia doesn't have it), so I guess this terminology is obsolete. Is there any newer terminology for the centroid of a ring?

---

**Edit (28, July, 2013)**

Thanks to user85319's suggestion of the book. So I'm posting here an extract of the book *Fields and Rings* by *Irving Kaplansky*.

I do have some questions left. First, on page 147, he gives the definition as follow:

> **Page 147**
>
> let $A$ be any ring, associated with an element $x \in A$, we have the right, and left multiplication:
>
> $$R(x):a \mapsto ax$$
> $$L(x):a \mapsto xa$$
>
> The ring $E$ generated by all the $L$'s, and $R$'s are called the *envelop* of $A$ (which I take to be the same as $\text{B}(R)$ in Herstein's definition). It is the subring of the ring of all endomorphism of the Abelian group $A$. The general element of $E$ is the sum of terms, each of which is the product of $L$'s, and $R$'s.
>
> **When $E$ is assiciative, the general term of the element in $E$ takes on the simplier form:**
>
> $$L(a) + R(b) + \sum L(c_i)R(d_i)$$
>
> We think of $E$ as placed on the right of $A$, and in this way $A$ becomes a right $E-$module. **Examining the relevant definition, we see that $A$ is simple iff it's an irreducible $E-$module.**

What I don't understand are the two bolded parts above. I have no idea about the second part, but I have some on the first part.

What I'm not sure is **why $E$ needs to be associative**? Say I have: $xL({a_1})R({b_1})L({a_2})R({b_2}) = a_2a_1xb_1b_2 = xL({a_2a_1})R({b_2b_1})$, i.e, I can kind of *combining* many of the left, and right multiplications into one pair of $L(c)R(d)$, and I can do the same to the other terms without using the fact that $E$ is associative. Am I missing something?

Thank you guys very much,

And have a good day.

Comment: If $R$ is just an additive group, then what is $xa$ when $x,a\in R$? I assume, instead, that $R$ is a ring, and $\text{End}(R)$ is just considering endomorphisms of the additive group of $R$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, $R$ is a ring, but by $\text{End}(R)$, the author means that he just considers all endomorphism of the additive group $R$.

Comment: If $C$ is the center of $R$, then it seems like there is some relationship here between the centroid and the tensor algebra $R\otimes_{C} R^{\text{op}}$, where $R^{op}$ is the ring with the same elements as $R$ but with multiplication reversed.

Comment: Uhm, can you please check my answer at the bottom of this post? Thank you so much :) :*

Answer (score 2):

Centroids (and extended centroids) play a role in the theory of (generalized) polynomial identities and functional identities in rings. One of the more recent books in this direction is *Functional Identities* by Matej Bresar, Mikhail A. Chebotar, Wallace S. Martindale.

Comment: The definition seems a little bit abstract, can you give me an example, pls?

Comment: For specific examples see Fields and Rings by Irving Kaplansky, p. 148. If you don't have it, I can write some down.

Comment: I wasn't able to comment the original question, that seems to require 50 reputation.

Comment: @user85319: Hi, thanks for your help, I don't think you need to type it, I do have the book. But on page 147 of that same book, the author writes: "When $E$ is associative, the general element of $E$ takes on the simplier form: $L(a) + R(b) + \sum L(c_i)R(d_i)$". I don't understand it. Isn't $E$ already associative? (As composition of functions is ofcourse associative) Or am I missing something here? :(

Comment: To be useful to others, it is best to make questions and answers as self-contained as possible. It would be good to include here enough of what is on p. 148 so that no one needs to buy a copy of *Functional Identities* to understand this answer.

Comment: @robjohn and user85319: Hi, can you check my answer at the bottom of this post? Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after thinking for a while (actually, for more than a day), is it true that the centroid of some ring $R$ is the set of all endomorphisms of the $R-$bimodule $R$?

I think it is, because: Let $\tau \in \text{C}(R)$, where $\text{C}(R)$ denotes the centroid of $R$. Then we'll have:

1. $\tau(a + b) = \tau(a) + \tau(b)$, since we can view $\tau$ to be some additive group endomorphism of $R$.
2. $\tau(a.b) = \tau(T_b(a)) = T_b(\tau(a)) = \tau(a).b$.
3. $\tau(a.b) = \tau(L_a(b)) = L_a(\tau(b)) = a.\tau(b)$.

Is it true? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's not clear how $L_aT_b$ is an endomorphism of the $R$-bimodule. It is not the case that that $L_aT_b(r_1rr_2)=r_1(L_aT_br)r_2$, is it?

Comment: Note that the endomorphism of $R$ as a left-$R$-module is isomorphic to $R$, so the bimodule endomorphisms, which are all left-endomorphisms,  necessarily form a subring of $R$, while the centroid is bigger than $R$.

Comment: No, I didn't claim that $L_a$, or $T_b$ is endomorphism of $R-$bimodule. I'm just using the fact that $\tau \in \text{C}(R)$ commutes with all $L$'s, and $T$'s. Or am I misunderstanding you? :(

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the question, and thought $B$ was the centroid.